# ZFS over LUKS over (NBD or NFS)? Need encrypted replication solution

Tags: storage, replication, zfs, luks

I am using ZFS(ZoL) over LUKS on home and on remote server.
All is working perfectly and fast. I do snapshots by cron, but now I want to replicate them to some backup storage.
I have a small 2-HDD dlink dns-323 nas, on which I have debian installed. 
My requirement is to have backups encrypted. I am not sure I can install ZFS and Luks into NAS. 
My question may be very stupid, I know it sounds crazy, but I have only one idea in this scenario.
Create LUKS and ZPOOL on NAS, but unlock and run it remotely by LAN on a workstation. By NFS or NBD. 
How that sounds? If my lan connection is stable and ok, will it run fine? I thought about rsync, zfs send/gpg, but I need an ability to remove some snapshots on backup box and want it to be managed automatically, and keep synced with master.
Any ideas?

Comment: It isn't complete automatic, but scripted easily.  I been using [borg](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for remote backups.  It supports encryption.

Comment: Thanks, I know about other backup tools, and used duplicity before. Was very cool. But now after discovering ZFS, I want to use it's features. In such backup systems like borg or duplicity you can't remove intermediary backups for N period, just because you don't need them anymore. And you keep all synced and automatically removing unneeded snapshots

Comment: `In such backup systems like borg ... you can't remove intermediary backups for N period` - Yes, you can.  It isn't automatic, but with borg I can make backups every day, and for backups older then a week only keep one a week, dropping the intermediate dailies.  I get the idea of liking ZFS, and wanting to take advantages of the features, but I kinda **like having my backup system operating using a different technology from my production system**, just in case that production decides to get fubar'd, I don't want that to mean my backups are also screwed.